# Selenium: How to get the changing value of a webelement in a for loop

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the value of weblement which changes with time. values are -`Pending, Approved, Received`.

I have to stop the loop when the value is changed to `Received`. I tried below code but it runs successfully for one loop and then stop in the second loop with error that `webelement not found with the given xpath`.

```
for(int i=0;i<=50;i++)
{
    String exactvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td")).getText();
        if (exactvalue.equals("Received"))
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("executing sleep interrupted");
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace Below line from your code.

Your code :

```
String exactvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td")).getText();
```

Replace with :

```
String exactvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr["+i+"]/td")).getText();
```

Comment: The webelement value exists at xpath=//tr[2]/td and I am trying to refresh the page 50 times and break the loop whenever the value of the webelement is changed to 'Received'. It runs first time fine but on the second time it errors out giving error that webelement xpath is not correct. I think refreshing the page is causing the selenium to loose the focus. if I try your code it will keep getting the text at xpath=//tr[0]/td, //tr[1]/td, //tr[2]/td, //tr[3]/td and so on which is not correct. My webelement value is located at //tr[2]/td.

Comment: If you need specific one element like you said `//tr[2]/td` then what's the meaning of using for loop over here? Can you update me. because for me if does not make any sense to use here for loop.

Comment: Make sure what you are asking and what you are trying to do, these two terms should be clear and please next time ask question with proper html details or site url along with your proper tried code.